# Ubuntu 17.04 Error when create VPN-connection: No plugin supported adding this connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I use Ubuntu 17.04, there was such problem at creation of VPN connection I receive an error "No plugin supported adding this connection".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjFhJ.png)

Perhaps someone had a similar problem. How to fix it?

PS. Or maybe someone knows how to reset all the settings of NetworkManager, if you just delete and set all the settings are saved. Also, if you delete the configuration folder, it is not recreated.

Comment: try `sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn` from terminal and try again.

Comment: Olimjon, not working. network-manager-openvpn installed on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try install `network-manager-openvpn` and `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` with:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

then log out, and log back in, and if that doesn't work, try a reboot. Also make sure `openvpn` itself is installed:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error message was incorrect, Network Manager was unable to add the connection because I'd renamed the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. A simple mkdir fixed the issue.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```